# Mexico - transfer in Schengen Area without visa - Morocco

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, tickets, schengen-visas

I'm russian. I don't have a Schengen visa and I don't have an opportunity to get one now.

I want to buy a ticket **Mexico - Brussels - Morroco** of **tuifly**.

Example:

[image: kiwi.com air ticket]

Normaly, if I had a **single ticket** , I wouldn't need a visa to do a transfer in Brussels without changing an airport, even though I didn't have a Schengen visa.

However, the route `Cancún - Brussels - Enfidha` doesn't exist at the website of **tuifly**. And **kiwi.com** does have such tickets. This implies that probably there'll be 2 **separate** tickets, of the same airline.

I'd buy them from kiwi.

The email support of **tuifly** told me that they couldn't give me an answer about me being able to board a flight, by email. Only in the airport, when boarding, would I find that out.

Question: will I likely be permitted to board a flight? How to increase my chances for this particular route?

Comment: But that flight left two days ago!

Comment: @MichaelHampton oh my God, really? I must run, run.....

Comment: Seriously though, kiwi likes to sell "single" tickets which actually turn out to be seaprate bookings and require passing through immigration and customs to change flights. This is very risky if you require a visa to enter the country in which your flights connect. Their so-called guarantee does not cover this situation. If you already have such a visa, it's no problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton re-read my question

Comment: "Re-read my question" is not useful. Is there something in particular you think I missed? If so, you should point it out explicitly. With the information given, I believe you would get separate tickets, and I do not believe you will be allowed to board this flight, and if you do manage to get on the flight, I suspect you would be refused entry in Brussels and returned to Mexico. I think it is not safe to book these tickets.

Comment: @MichaelHampton and your comments are useful. Know the answer -- post it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is it not possible to check in for the second flight either online or inside the international area of the airport?  I think the only problem would be an inability to board the flight to Brussels, but I suspect that it wouldn't be possible to overcome that inability.

Comment: @phoog Sure, it might be possible. I've just seen too many people get burned by buying tickets at kiwi.com and then being denied boarding or being unable to change flights because they actually got separate tickets. I'm not willing to advise anyone who might require a visa to buy from that site or any like it without being 100% certain they won't have a problem, and I'm not 100% certain.